# History of the /etc directory

Tags: linux, unix

It seems like the `/etc` directory was added for anything that falls into the "et cetera" category of system files.  To me that seems along the lines of "extra" or "unnecessary".

Why is it that (in my experience) `/etc` is now the goto directory for installing programs and libraries?

**UPDATE**: So it's for installing configuration files; but that still doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Section 3.7 refers http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen binaries in `/etc`...

Comment: You're right, my mistake.  As MDMarra pointed out, it's for configuration... which still doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Our sister site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) will probably be a much more welcoming place for questions about Unix history.

Comment: your question reads like trolling. more suited to tech battlefront forum

Comment: Not intentionally trolling, was just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And the answer is "Because it was for `et cetera` - `and others`." It wasn't always just config files.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5665/what-does-etc-stand-for

[Question for Dr. Salus: final word](http://www.groklaw.net/comment.php?mode=display&sid=2007030308154032&title=Question%20for%20Dr.%20Salus%3A%20final%20word&type=article&order=ASC&hideanonymous=0&pid=542561#c542641)

As a footnote, I just received email from Dennis Ritchie
stating:

> I assure you that the original contents of /etc were the "et cetera"
>   that didn't seem to fit elsewhere. Other variants might do their own
>   etymologies differently.
>
> Regards, Dennis

Answer (score 8):

You're a bit mistaken it seems. Programs and libraries shouldn't be installed there. It's where configuration files should be placed.

The [manpage for the file system heirarchy](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier) explains this in more detail.

Comment: So why isn't the directory called `conf`?

Comment: You'll have to ask someone that was at AT&T or Berkley in the 60s.

Comment: OK, if that's your question, you're off-topic because you're inviting extended discussion, about what is essentially a non-technical topic. It's called /etc because that's what the original authors of the OS called it.